# In a D3 Script force directed graph, I want to make my nodes larger but my arrow markers disappear after a certain size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on modifying sample code from the book d3.js in Action to create a  force directed graph. I want to increase the size of nodes to so the labels fit inside size. But after a certain size, the arrow markers disappear and I can't find a reason why. It's a simple script. If nothing else is there a good site that I can use as a reference for coding d3.js. or how I can put the labels inside the nodes a different way that would work. What I found so far isn't much help. The script is below.

```
 var marker = d3.select("svg").append('defs').append('marker')  
    .attr("id", "Triangle")  
    .attr("refX", 12)  
    .attr("refY", 6)  
    .attr("markerUnits", 'userSpaceOnUse')  
    .attr("markerWidth", 12)  
    .attr("markerHeight", 18)  
    .attr("orient", 'auto')  
    .append('path')  
    .attr("d", 'M 0 0 12 6 0 12 3 6');
        
queue()  
    .defer(d3.csv, "Data/MM68_NL.csv")
    .defer(d3.csv, "Data/MM68_MT.csv")
    .await(function(error, file1, file2) { createForceLayout(file1, file2); });

function createForceLayout(nodes,edges) {

    var nodeHash = {};

    for (x in nodes) {
        nodeHash[nodes[x].id] = nodes[x];
    }

    for (x in edges) {
        edges[x].weight = parseInt(edges[x].weight);
        edges[x].source = nodeHash[edges[x].source];
        edges[x].target = nodeHash[edges[x].target];
    }
  

    var weightScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(edges, 
 function (d) { return d.weight })).range([.1, 1])

    force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(function (d) {return d.weight * -500})
        .gravity(.3)
        .size([500,500]).nodes(nodes)
        .links(edges).on("tick", forceTick);

    d3.select("svg").selectAll("line.link").data(edges, function (d) {return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id}).enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("opacity", .5)
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) {return d.weight});
  
    var nodeEnter = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function (d) {return d.id}).enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag())
        .on("click", fixNode);
  
    function fixNode(d) {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 4);
        d.fixed = true;
    }
  
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5) //size of the nodes
        .style("fill", "lightgray")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("y", 15)
        .text(function(d) {return d.id})

        d3.selectAll("line").attr("marker-end", "url(#Triangle)");

    force.start();

    function forceTick() {
        d3.selectAll("line.link")
            .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x})
            .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x})
            .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y})
            .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y});
  
        d3.selectAll("g.node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"})
  }
}
```

'''

[image: Before]

[image: After resize]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant way to render arrows as a single `path` without markers.

```js
const arrowPath = (source, target, arrowWidth, arrowHeadHeight) => {
  const dx = target.x - source.x;
  const dy = target.y - source.y;
  const distance = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  
  const sx = dy * arrowWidth / distance;
  const sy = dx * arrowWidth / distance;
  const ax = dx * arrowHeadHeight / distance;
  const ay = dy * arrowHeadHeight / distance;
  
  return `M ${source.x - sx},${source.y + sy} 
    L ${target.x - sx - ax},${target.y + sy - ay}
    L ${target.x - 2 * sx - ax},${target.y + 2 * sy - ay}
    L ${target.x},${target.y}
    L ${target.x + 2 * sx - ax},${target.y - 2 * sy - ay}
    L ${target.x + sx - ax},${target.y - sy - ay}
    L ${source.x + sx},${source.y - sy}
    Z`
}

const p1 = {x: 20, y: 30};
const p2 = {x: 120, y: 150};
const p3 = {x: 140, y: 170};
const p4 = {x: 250, y: 40};

const svg = d3.select('svg');


svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', arrowPath(p1, p2, 5, 20))
  .attr('fill', 'yellow')
  .attr('stroke', 'red');
  
svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', arrowPath(p3, p4, 7, 30))
  .attr('fill', 'green')
  .attr('stroke', 'blue');
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width='300' height='180'>
</svg>
```